# js: undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I've js file with embeded ruby code:

```
function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    var hello = <%= current_user.name %>;
    $scope.greeting = hello;
  };
}
```

But I've catch an error `undefined local variable or method current_user` which points on

`= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true`

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you try to access the variable from within an asset file? This won't work, as those are compiled statically and not dynamically for every request

Comment: @PeterSorowka It seems you are right. Can you tell, should I try it in view directory?

Comment: You should try to structure your code so that your assets do not depend on request runtime variables. For your example, you could pass the username as an argument to `sayHello`. You would then still define the *function* in assets, but the *call* as inline JavaScript within your template

Answer (score 3):

Use gon gem https://github.com/gazay/gon the easiest way to pass data from your rails environment to your javascript environement (in other words: from your server to your client).

in your controller

```
# Make sure first that current_user is not nil
gon.current_user_name = current_user.name
# As you can see we don't pass the whole `current_user` but only the data we need
#   gon and javascript won't know how to use your Rails objects
#   so pass only strings, integers, arrays and hashs
#   (but you'll figure out all of this by your self, it's pretty natural)
```

in your layout (more info on gon installation can be found in gon github pages)

```
<head>
  <%= include_gon %>
  ...
```

in your javascript

```
var hello = gon.current_user_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

**JS**

To extend `Benjamin Sinclaire`'s answer, you have to remember Rails is a `back-end` system; JS is `front-end`.

This means all of the Rails variables are only available in the Rails files in the backend - what your browser receives is a pre-rendered set of `HTML` files, populated with your data

The problem you have is that JS cannot read `Rails` data without having that data *translated* from Rails into "JS". All JS sees is the [`DOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) - the HTML elements on your page

--

**Data**

In order to share variables such as `current_user` in your JS / `front-end`, you basically need to pass it through to the HTML layer

You can  either do this by setting a hidden element (and setting its [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)), or  by setting the variable in your `layout`

As mentioned, the most efficient way to do this is to use the [`gon`](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem, which `Benjamin Sinclaire` has discussed